# $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N $ is injective $ \implies $ $\lim\Big(f(n)\Big)=+ \infty $?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N $ is an injective function , then for the sequence $\Big(f(n)\Big)$ do we have $\lim\Big(f(n)\Big)=+ \infty  $ ?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. You want to show that for any $m\in \mathbb N$, there is some $N$ such that 
$$n> N\implies f(n)>m.$$
Since $f$ is injective, the set $f^{-1}(\{0,\ldots,m\})$ has at most $m+1$ points. Let $N$ be the largest of these. Then if $n> N$, $n\notin f^{-1}(\{0,\ldots,m\})$ so $f(n)>m$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the negation: 
$$\exists A>0 ,\quad \forall B>0, \quad n\ge B\; \text{and}\; f(n)<A$$
then pick any $B$ and
$$f\colon \left\{\lfloor B\rfloor+1,\ldots\right\}\rightarrow \left\{1,\ldots,\lfloor A\rfloor\right\}$$
is also injective which's a contradiction due to the cardinality of the two sets.

Comment: The first translation of the negation is at best ambiguous (what does "$n\geqslant B$ and $f(n)\lt A$" mean? "$\forall n\geqslant B,\ f(n)\lt A$"? "$\exists n\geqslant B,\ f(n)\lt A$"?) but the rest of the post shows you interpret the negation of "to converge to infinity" as "to be bounded". This is wrong. // @upvoters Why the upvote?